# generate hazy images with dark channel prior

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to generate some hazy images by reversing the process of dark channel prior with python,i think i calculate transmission and global atmospheric light correctly,but the output is a weird image.

Base on atmospheric scattering model ,I=Jt+A if indexes pixels x is ignored.
I:hazy images , J:non-haze image , t:transmission , A:global atmospheric light

I try to switching to equation like this:
    1)I=Jt+A  from many thesis
    2)I=(J-A)t+A from a github code
    and the forms with subject J,but output is still not correct.

output image:

without haze:
[image]

dark channel:
[image]

transmission:
[image]

weird blue haze image(when I=Jt+A):
[image]

```
printing bgr matrix of first 5*5 area:
format:[[[b g r] ... [b g r]]...[[b g r] ... [b g r]]]
[[[231.59398459 177.90628817 135.79826498]
  [231.59398459 177.90628817 135.79826498]
  [231.59398459 177.90628817 135.79826498]
  [231.59398459 177.90628817 135.79826498]
  [231.59398459 177.90628817 135.79826498]]

 [[231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]]

 [[231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]]

 [[231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]]

 [[231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]
  [231.64794239 177.96024596 135.85222257]]]
```

main function of code:

```
#load pic  
img="./test.jpg"  
src=cv2.imread(img);  
J=src.astype("float64")/255;  

dark=DarkChannel(J,15);
A=AtmLight(J,dark);
te=TransmissionEstimate(J,A,15);
t=TransmissionRefine(src,te);

tx=0.1
I=np.empty(J.shape,J.dtype)
t=cv2.max(t,tx)
for i in range(0,3):
   I[:,:,i]=(J[:,:,i]*t)+A[0,i]

#output
cv2.imshow('I',I);
```

For basic functions DarkChannel,AtmLight,TransmissionEstimate,TransmissionRefine:
https://pastebin.com/3uCqamfA

Basic functions are not my implementation, but it run correctly and similar to the example code of a thesis.

latest output:
[image]

Comment: If the equation is *Jt+A*, why do you write *J-t+A* in your code?

Comment: In any case, check the range of the output, your result image looks like you are saturating the colors. It could be a display issue, I don't know how you display your images...

Comment: that is a typo,it is fixed and new information is added.eg:part of matrix of output, and code for printing image.

Comment: Why are you treating `t` and `A` as scalars? Isn't at least `t` an image (you're showing it in your question). If so, it should probably be `I[:,:,i]=(J[:,:,i]*t)+A` or something like that.

Comment: Yes,you are right for t.It should be I[:,:,i]=(J[:,:,i]*t)+A[0,i].A is 1*3 matrix,each value relate to one of rgb channel,so A is correct.But output still not correct. latest output is attached at the end.

Comment: “Haze” is a very light-touch effect, have you tried winding down the A and increasing the t? Or if you want a “mist” or “fog” effect, you need an equation that includes distance.

Comment: I tested some new parameter for what you suggested.It look matter but still weird,image's tone shift greatly to blue.
All images are prepare for training a Dehaze CNN,so it should as real as possible.I think my approach is fail,if you have some better way to do that,please share.

Comment: Try giving it some known data and check the result against known good outputs or manually calculated results. The maths isn’t exactly complicated. Use a very small image so you can check each pixel, DEBUG it rather than just looking at the picture and saying it is wrong.